# Celery Result backend. DisabledBackend object has no attribute _get_task_meta_for

Tags: python, celery

I have configured celery and the backend:

```
cleryapp = Celery(
    'tasks_app', brocker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
    backend='db+postgresql://guest@localhost:5432'
)
```

'results' appears disabled when i start the worker, but I read on another question here that that's not the issue.

The database is getting all the data correctly, but

```
result = AsyncResult(task_id)
```

raises

```
AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'
```

Comment: Try using `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` through settings.

Comment: the starting stdout shows the correct results address now... but the exact same exception is raised...

Answer (score 32):

I found a more convenient way to do that.

```
result = celery.AsyncResult(task_id)
```

`celery` is the Celery instance of your application, not the celery module.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider putting code components inside code blocks. For example, `celery` instead of *celery*.

Answer (score 8):

try using this instead where task is the name of your task function:

```
result = task.AsyncResult(task_id)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try:

```
from celery import result, Celery
app = Celery(backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')
res = result.AsyncResult(id='7037247e-f528-43ba-bce5-ee0e30704c58', app=app)
print(res.info)
```

Answer (score 0):

just like it said [celery](http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/celery/celery/q/stackoverflow/23215311/celery-with-rabbitmq-attributeerror-39disabledbackend39-object-has-no-attribute) , you should specify the value of backend,
just like: `app = Celery("tasks", broker='mongodb://localhost:27017/test',backend='mongodb://localhost:27017/test1')`

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the `task` also in your `AyscResult` script to let celery know the backend setting. I have faced the similar issue (`AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'`) with the backend well configured and this help me a lot.

```
from <your celery app> import <tasks> # add this one
from celery.result AsyncResult

result = AsyncResult(task_id)
print(result.state) # check if it worked or not, it should
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are also coming from django background might be tempted to use : `from celery.result import AsyncResult` in the shell.

However, remember that in django we are using `python manage.py shell`. There is a lot of configuration settings that django does behind the scene.

In other applications that might not be the case, especially with normal python shell. That's why we have to explicitly specially our own celery app.

e.g. if your main.py looks like this:

```
from celery import current_app

def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI()
    celery_app = current_app
    celery_app.config_from_object(config.settings, namespace="CELERY")
```

You can use the below code in a normal python shell.

```
(env)  ✘ ⚙ ss@nofoobar  ~/Documents/fastapi-celery  python

>>> from main import celery
>>> from celery.result import AsyncResult
>>> AsyncResult("e3d3ef1c-65a5-4045-87c1-014aa159f52f")
```