# Celery worker not consuming task and not retrieving results

Tags: python, celery

I'm using Celery with RabbitMQ as the broker and redis as the result backend. I'm now manually dispatching tasks to the worker. I can get the task IDs as soon as I sent the tasks out. But actually Celery worker did not work on them. I cannot see the resulted files on my disk. And later when I want to use `AsyncResult` to check the results, of course I got `AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'`

I checked RabbitMQ and redis, they're both working (`redis-cli ping`). The log also says `Connected to amqp://myuser:**@127.0.0.1:5672/myvhost`.

Another interesting thing is that I actually have another remote server consuming the tasks connected to the broker. It also logs "Connected to amqp", but the two the nodes cannot see each other: `mingle: searching for neighbors, mingle: all alone`. The system worked before. I wonder where should I start to look for clues. Thanks.

Comment: please show your celeryconfig, a sample of your task definition and your task invocation code

Comment: Maybe you have not set the CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND. Refer this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215311/celery-with-rabbitmq-attributeerror-disabledbackend-object-has-no-attribute

Comment: Here is another question you could refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309035/celery-result-backend-disabledbackend-object-has-no-attribute-get-task-meta-fo

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `AttributeError` message, adding a `backend` config setting similar to below should help resolve it:

`app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//', backend='amqp://')`

Answer (score 0):

My celery version is 4.2.1. I set CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND to 'rpc://' and solve this problem.

See also [celery result_backend configuration document](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-result_backend)