# django celery AsyncResult AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'

Tags: django, asynchronous, celery

I am using django celery(4.2) and I will add some task from my django view, also I want to get the task result async in a separate process, but when I try to get the result, I got some errors.

My full steps is as following:

1. django celery config:

proj/settings/celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Nuwa.settings.development')

app = Celery('Nuwa')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

proj/settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = f'redis://{REDIS["HOST"]}:{REDIS["PORT"]}'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = f'redis://{REDIS["HOST"]}:{REDIS["PORT"]}'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

proj/settings/**init**.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app', )
```

2. call celery task in one django view:

```
result = port_scan.delay(target)
redis_conn.sadd(celery_task_set_key, result.task_id)
```

in this step, I store the task_id in redis set for future use.

3. get the task result

```
redis_conn = redis.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT)
celery_tasks = redis_conn.smembers('celery-tasks')


for task_id in celery_tasks:
    print(task_id)
    celery_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
    print(celery_result.state)
```

when I try to get the result, it have error:

```
AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'
```

I try some solutions by search google and so, it doesn't work.

Comment: Even though it's "just a string" in the error - `'DisabledBackend'` sounds - disabled? Might also be a duplicate - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309035/celery-result-backend-disabledbackend-object-has-no-attribute-get-task-meta-fo and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215311/celery-with-rabbitmq-attributeerror-disabledbackend-object-has-no-attribute (even though this uses Rabbit, I think this is more about Celery config then the different backends)

Comment: @Risadinha I tried all the solution you said, but it did't work

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue when we upgraded from Celery 3.x to 4.x. Tried various solutions but the simplest is just to use the [set_default](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.set_default). So, in `celery.py`, need to add this:

```py
app.set_default()
```

This makes sure that calls to `AsyncResult(task_id)` will use the fully configured/bootstrapped version of Celery app (i.e. uses your set `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND`), instead of the original/default version (i.e. uses the `DisabledBackend`).